# How to convert a dyadic formatted dataset to an adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

I have been trying hard to convert the following dyadic df to an adjacency matrix, working with several different approaches (reshape, dcast, ...) but didn't get what I wanted so far (It's a very long df, which is why I only add some exemplary lines here):

```
cntry1   cntry2    var1
usa      canada      70
usa      bahamas     29
usa      cuba        39 
canada   bahamas     15
canada   cuba        35
cuba     bahamas     5
```

I'd like to have the above df in the following format:

```
            usa  canada bahamas  cuba     
usa         0    70        29      39
canada     70     0        15      35
bahamas    29    15        0        5
cuba       39    35        5        0
```

If I understood the various packages right (I am quite new to R), I would need to convert it from long to wide, which -however- is usually only done with edgelists of one id variable.

Using it for my case, I receive the error message "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length", which tells me that there seem to be non-unique values? - after reducing it to unique values the adjacency matrix is either complete for the rows or the columns but not both.

Is there any completely different approach you would recommend me to use?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Could you also show the expected output.  I run the code.  I am getting usa canada results same instead of being different.

Comment: I updated the solution again. Check if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 lvls <- unique(unlist(dat[,1:2]))[c(1,2,4,3)]
  dat[,1:2] <- lapply(dat[,1:2], function(x) factor(x, levels=lvls))
  r1 <- xtabs(var1~cntry2+cntry1, dat)
  r1[lower.tri(r1) & !r1] <- r1[upper.tri(r1) & !!r1]
  r1[upper.tri(r1) & !!r1] <- 0

 as.matrix(as.dist(r1)) #idea contributed by @alexis_laz
 #         usa canada bahamas cuba
 #usa       0     70      29   39
 #canada   70      0      15   35
 #bahamas  29     15       0    5
 #cuba     39     35       5    0
```

Or

```
 library(igraph)
 res <-  get.adjacency(graph.edgelist(as.matrix(dat[,1:2]),directed=FALSE)) #using the original dataset
 res[lower.tri(res)] <- dat$var1
 res[upper.tri(res)] <- t(res)[upper.tri(res)]
 res
 #4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
 #        usa canada bahamas cuba
 #usa       .     70      29   39
 #canada   70      .      15   35
 #bahamas  29     15       .    5
 #cuba     39     35       5    .
```

#### Update

Assuming that you have a dataset (undirected) like this:

```
 dat <- structure(list(cntry1 = c("usa", "usa", "usa", "canada", "canada", 
 "cuba", "canada"), cntry2 = c("canada", "bahamas", "cuba", "bahamas", 
 "cuba", "bahamas", "usa"), var1 = c(70L, 29L, 39L, 15L, 35L, 
 5L, 40L)), .Names = c("cntry1", "cntry2", "var1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

 lvls <- unique(unlist(dat[,1:2]))[c(1,2,4,3)]
 dat[,1:2] <- lapply(dat[,1:2], function(x) factor(x, levels=lvls))
 r1 <- xtabs(var1~cntry2+cntry1, dat)
 r2 <- t(r1)
 indx <- intersect(which(lower.tri(r2) & !!r2), which(lower.tri(r1) & !r1))
 r1[lower.tri(r1) & !r1] <- r2[indx]

 indx1 <- upper.tri(r1) & !r1
 r1[indx1] <- r2[indx1]
 r1
 #              cntry1
 #cntry2    usa canada bahamas cuba
 #usa       0     40      29   39
 #canada   70      0      15   35
 #bahamas  29     15       0    5
 #cuba     39     35       5    0
```

#### Update No:2

```
 dat <- structure(list(cntry1 = c("usa", "usa", "usa", "canada", "canada", "cuba",  "canada"),
   cntry2 = c("canada", "bahamas", "cuba", "bahamas", "cuba", "bahamas", "usa"), 
  var1 = c(4.5L, 3L, 0.5L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 5.5L)), 
  .Names = c("cntry1", "cntry2", "var1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Change the values that are `0` in the `var1` column to any other value not in the dataset

```
 dat$var1[!dat$var1] <- 0.01
 lvls <- unique(unlist(dat[,1:2]))[c(1,2,4,3)]
 dat[,1:2] <- lapply(dat[,1:2], function(x) factor(x, levels=lvls))
 r1 <- xtabs(var1~cntry2+cntry1, dat)
 r2 <- t(r1)
 indx <- intersect(which(lower.tri(r2) & !!r2), which(lower.tri(r1) & !r1))
 r1[lower.tri(r1) & !r1] <- r2[indx]

 indx1 <- upper.tri(r1) & !r1
 r1[indx1] <- r2[indx1]
 r1[r1==0.01] <- 0
  r1
  #         cntry1
 #cntry2   usa canada bahamas cuba
 # usa     0.0    5.5     3.0  0.5
 # canada  4.5    0.0     2.0  0.0
 # bahamas 3.0    2.0     0.0  2.0
 # cuba    0.5    0.0     2.0  0.0
```

Comment: +1. just a format improvement: last line could be `as.matrix(as.dist(xtabs(var1 ~ cntry2 + cntry1, dat)))`

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first approach works perfectly well for my case!  Do you maybe also have an idea about how to adapt it for cases in which  USA-Canada might have a different value than Canada-USA (undirected)?

Comment: @Dan I can't view the full comment. only up till (I realized that -)

Comment: Sorry, this will be my last question!   Applying this solution to various dfs and checking the results throroughly I unfortunately found serious problems with cases that include 0. One equally structured dataset that includes values between 0 and 10 (including 0.5 etc.) renders correct results for all but cases with a 0 before the comma. For a dummy-coded variable, however, all values are changed!? Is that possible?

Comment: @Dan It is best that you post the question as a new topic.  Also, it would be easy if you can show the input and expected results as it is not clear "cases with a 0 before the comma".

Comment: Thanks!   I am talking about all cases <1 (in my special case 0/0.5).  I'll answer below with more information.

Comment: @Dan It might be better if you post a new question as you may get more response

Answer (score 0):

With

```
library(reshape2)
dat = rbind(dat, data.frame(cntry1=dat$cntry2, cntry2=dat$cntry1, var1=dat$var1))
casted = dcast(dat, cntry1 ~ cntry2, fill=0)
```

I get

```
  cntry1 bahamas canada cuba usa
1  canada      15      0   35  70
2    cuba       5     35    0  39
3     usa      29     70   39   0
4 bahamas       0     15    5  29
```

which seems to be what you want, although not reordered.

Answer (score 0):

It might be efficient to use a sparse matrix (although the example you've given isn't particularly sparse):

Get data:

```
dd <- read.table(text="
    cntry1    cntry2         var1
    usa      canada            70
    usa      bahamas         29
    usa      cuba                39 
    canada    bahamas      15
    canada    cuba             35
    cuba       bahamas         5 ",
   header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

There may be a slicker way to do this:

```
library(Matrix)
r <- sort(unique(c(dd$cntry1,dd$cntry2)))
f1 <- as.numeric(factor(dd$cntry1,levels=r))
f2 <- as.numeric(factor(dd$cntry2,levels=r))
m <- Matrix(0,nrow=length(r),ncol=length(r),dimnames=list(r,r))
m[cbind(f1,f2)] <- dd$var1
forceSymmetric(m,uplo="L")
```